# Получение содержимого из PHP средставми ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Здравствуйте, надо получить из php - url картинки и 4 имени кнопки и заменить существующие. Обязательно ли использовать JSON? Если да, то как это реализовать?

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<img src="#" id="img_load">

<a href="#" name="button1" data-num="1" class="button">кнопка</a>
<a href="#" name="button2" data-num="2" class="button">кнопка</a>
<a href="#" name="button3" data-num="3" class="button">кнопка</a>
<a href="#" name="button4" data-num="4" class="button">кнопка</a>

<div class="results"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('.button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var img = $('#img_load');
        var current = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'setings.php',
            data: 'btn=' + current.data('num'),
            success: function(data){
                $('.results').html(data);
                img.attr('src', 'image url');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Использовать JSON не обязательно: можно передавать ссылки простым текстом.

Comment: у меня есть 4 кнопки, нужно поменять их на Васю, Петю,Рому,Колю, что то я вообще не могу понять

Comment: Никто не запрещает прислать ссылки простым текстом (строка, содержащая ссылки, разделённые, например, запятыми). После чего разбить `data` на массив и присвоить нужным кнопкам нужные значения ссылок из этого массива.

Comment: а конкретней можно про разбитие или где можно прочитать

Comment: В классе `String` есть метод [.split()](http://javascript.ru/String/split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случе, я считаю, лучше всего json:

На сервере:

```
{
   "src" : "http://......",
   "btn_1" : "Кнопка 1",
   "btn_2" : "Кнопка 2",
   "btn_3" : "Кнопка 3",
   "btn_4" : "Кнопка 4"
 }
```

В JS:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'setings.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'btn=' + current.data('num'),
        success: function(data){ 
            $('#img_load').attr('src', data.src);
             $('.button').each(function(i,e){
                $(this).text(data["btn_"+(i+1)]);//Вместо (i+1) можно было бы $(this).attr('data-num'); использовать, но в данном случае можно и обойтись (i - index - от 0 считается, поэтому +1)
              });
        }
    });
```

Если нигде не ошибся - должно сработать.

Можно однако и без json и тут 2 варианта:

1) заключить всю перезагружаемую область (картинки и кнопку) в отдельный див (скажем, `<div id="block1">...</div>`) и потом подгружая страницу с обнавленными даннами просто тупо перезаписывать содержимое этого div ( `$('#block1').html($(data).find('#block1').html());`)

Вариант 2й - по отдельности, примерно как ты делал:

```
       success: function(data) {
          $data = $(data);//Чтобы повторно не вызывать обработчик
          $('#img_load').attr('src', $data.find('#img_load').src);
          $data_btns = $data.find('.button');
             $('.button').each(function(i,e){
                $(this).text($data_btns.eq(i).text());//index i у них должен получиться одинаковым, но, при желании, мажно, для большей точности, присвоить кнопкам id - $(this).text($data.find('#'+this.id).text());
              });
       }
```

Comment: Не `format`, а `dataType` в параметрах Ajax запроса.

Comment: Пробую через JSON, масив получает, но что то ничего не происходит, для наглядность, только замену картинки оставил...

Comment: Regent, да, точно - благодарю!

Comment: 4uva4ok1905 во-первых, проверь json- массив через валидатор (загугль - json validator - их много), во-вторых, тут, как правильно Regent заметил - я опечатку format, а не dataType в параметрах указал, дальше надо смотреть, приходит ли data и что в этой data приходит

Comment: Нашел проблему Firebug, вместо data[0].src, просто data.src. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: В принципе да, моя ошибка: там же один объект получается - это я привык уже автоматически массив с объектами выводить

Answer (score 0):

[Доступ к атрибутам](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties)

ajax удобен тогда, когда вам не нужно перезагружать страницу.

Чтобы изменить атрибуты элемента в самом PHP, вам нужно написать нечто подобное

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">тут код изменения атрибута;</script>';
```

Только лучше обращаться к элементу по его ID, чем по его имени, потому как вы будете менять это имя, и будет путаница ппц